# How to create mirrored visualizations of binary variables on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not sure how to put into words exactly what I'm seeking to achieve, but essentially I'm stuck on how to turn this:

[image]

...into something like this:

[image]

I've tried searching for tips on how to accomplish a similar "mirroring" visualization but that inevitably results in guides for how to flip columns across the x-axis into positive and negative space. Here's the code i've used thus far:

```
view(senate2022)
senate2022 <- senate2022 %>%
  mutate(outcome = ifelse(seatprob_Dparty > seatprob_Rparty, "blue", "red") )
view(senate2022)

constant <- senate2022 %>%
  ggplot(aes(seatsheld, seatprob_Dparty, fill=outcome)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50)
constant
```

Here's the dput:

```
dput(senate2022)
structure(list(cycle = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), branch = c("Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate"), 
    expression = c("_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", 
    "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_lite", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", 
    "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_deluxe", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", 
    "_classic", "_classic", "_classic", "_classic"), forecastdate = c("11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", "11/8/22", 
    "11/8/22", "11/8/22"), seatprob_Dparty = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5e-05, 0.00025, NA, NA, NA, 7.5e-05, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 8e-04, 0.001475, 0.003725, 0.008525, 0.015625, 
    0.027175, 0.04625, 0.0663, 0.091, 0.1121, 0.121975, 0.12525, 
    0.11385, 0.105, 0.084425, 0.0484, 0.02085, 0.005225, 0.001375, 
    0.000225, 7.5e-05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5e-05, 2e-04, 
    0.000925, 0.00285, 0.007775, 0.0201, 0.040125, 0.0734, 0.116775, 
    0.152625, 0.176975, 0.162775, 0.126975, 0.0769, 0.031525, 
    0.008575, 0.00125, 0.000175, 2.5e-05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5e-05, 0.000225, 0.00065, 0.002575, 0.00675, 0.0155, 
    0.03275, 0.06085, 0.0936, 0.12415, 0.148425, 0.156575, 0.137, 
    0.107575, 0.0671, 0.032525, 0.01105, 0.002225, 3e-04, 1e-04, 
    2.5e-05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), seatprob_Rparty = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.5e-05, NA, NA, NA, 0.00025, 5e-05, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 7.5e-05, 0.000225, 0.001375, 0.005225, 0.02085, 
    0.0484, 0.084425, 0.105, 0.11385, 0.12525, 0.121975, 0.1121, 
    0.091, 0.0663, 0.04625, 0.027175, 0.015625, 0.008525, 0.003725, 
    0.001475, 8e-04, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.5e-05, 0.000175, 
    0.00125, 0.008575, 0.031525, 0.0769, 0.126975, 0.162775, 
    0.176975, 0.152625, 0.116775, 0.0734, 0.040125, 0.0201, 0.007775, 
    0.00285, 0.000925, 2e-04, 5e-05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2.5e-05, 1e-04, 3e-04, 0.002225, 0.01105, 0.032525, 0.0671, 
    0.107575, 0.137, 0.156575, 0.148425, 0.12415, 0.0936, 0.06085, 
    0.03275, 0.0155, 0.00675, 0.002575, 0.00065, 0.000225, 5e-05, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), seatsheld = c(99L, 98L, 97L, 96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 
    91L, 90L, 9L, 89L, 88L, 87L, 86L, 85L, 84L, 83L, 82L, 81L, 
    80L, 8L, 79L, 78L, 77L, 76L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 72L, 71L, 70L, 
    7L, 69L, 68L, 67L, 66L, 65L, 64L, 63L, 62L, 61L, 6L, 5L, 
    4L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 3L, 
    29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 60L, 59L, 58L, 
    57L, 56L, 55L, 54L, 53L, 52L, 51L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 
    45L, 44L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 20L, 2L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 
    15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 100L, 10L, 1L, 0L, 99L, 98L, 97L, 
    96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 91L, 90L, 9L, 89L, 88L, 87L, 86L, 
    85L, 84L, 83L, 82L, 81L, 80L, 8L, 79L, 78L, 77L, 76L, 75L, 
    74L, 73L, 72L, 71L, 70L, 7L, 69L, 68L, 67L, 66L, 65L, 64L, 
    63L, 62L, 61L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 
    33L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 3L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 
    22L, 21L, 60L, 59L, 58L, 57L, 56L, 55L, 54L, 53L, 52L, 51L, 
    50L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 45L, 44L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 20L, 
    2L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 100L, 10L, 
    1L, 0L, 99L, 98L, 97L, 96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 91L, 90L, 
    9L, 89L, 88L, 87L, 86L, 85L, 84L, 83L, 82L, 81L, 80L, 8L, 
    79L, 78L, 77L, 76L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 72L, 71L, 70L, 7L, 69L, 
    68L, 67L, 66L, 65L, 64L, 63L, 62L, 61L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 39L, 
    38L, 37L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 3L, 29L, 28L, 
    27L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 60L, 59L, 58L, 57L, 56L, 
    55L, 54L, 53L, 52L, 51L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 45L, 44L, 
    43L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 20L, 2L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 
    13L, 12L, 11L, 100L, 10L, 1L, 0L), simulations = c(40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 
    40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L, 40000L), timestamp =
```

See above - I was expecting two mirrored sets of columns for binary variables

Answer (score 1):

You'd get a reasonable match with:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ss <- !is.na(senate2022$seatsheld) & !is.na(senate2022$seatprob_Dparty)

ggplot(senate2022, aes(seatsheld, seatprob_Dparty, 
                       fill = seatsheld < weighted.mean(seatsheld[ss],
                                           seatprob_Dparty[ss]),
                       alpha = ifelse(abs(50.9 - seatsheld) > 1, 0.8, 1))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, labels = function(x) {
    ifelse(x < 50, paste0("<span style='color:#f86a68;'>", 100 - x), 
                  paste0("<span style='color:#5768ac;'>", x))
    }, breaks = 20:31 * 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#5768ac", "#f86a68"), guide = "none") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20, base_family = "Roboto Condensed",) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_markdown(face = "bold"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line())
```

[image]

Comment: This mostly works, but the scale_fill_manual bit's not working, as all I get are grey bars.

Comment: @opalwilderness it works on the data set that I created here, as you can see. Without seeing your own data, it's difficult to know how to fix this (that's why a reproducible data set is so important when asking a question here on SO) . Perhaps you could edit your question to include the output from `dput(senate2022)` so that I could fix this to work on your data set?

Comment: Ah I see your point - please see above (and thank you for your patience, I'm indeed quite new to this!)

Comment: One last question - how do I attain the 15/10/5% notation on the y-axis as pictured above (I must've cut that part out when taking a screenshot)?

Comment: I removed that on purpose @opalwilderness because I thought you didn't want it. Take out the line `axis.text.y = element_blank(),`. To add the percentage symbol, you will need to add the line `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = ~paste0(.x, '%'))` to your plot.

Comment: got it - that gives me 0.1%, 0.2%, etc. How do i get to 5,10,15%?

Comment: In that case, you can use `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` instead.